# Bolck downloading and uploading

Tags: vb.net

Dear Experts,
                I need a coding to block downloads and uploads for all browser like firefox,googlechrome,ie etc. on system in VB.NET

Thanks for your cosideration

Pardeep

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  Once data hits a user's browser you have no control over what they do with it.  What is it you're worried about?